# My whole form moves down a few pixels when I click my Save button and I want to avoid that

Tags: css, button, click

I wanted to create a fancy button that will look like it is getting clicked down when someone clicks on it.  Unfortunately, I’ve noticed on my Mac (both Chrome and Firefox latest browsers), when I click on the “Save” button, the entire div containing the form (identified by the “profile” id below) moves down a few pixels while I'm clicking the "Save" button.  I created this JSFiddle to demonstrate -- https://jsfiddle.net/05qxeaok/2/ .  I have

```
<div id="profile" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <form class="edit_user" id="edit_user_2" action="/users/2" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="zNwIQCm3caY33TTc1cs3j2yCVI8VVCWhNHR7RsUuY/d0hqYjeMTCtS85diQv6nKGcX8PbzXTZYHQqCVthMWh1A==" />

    <h2>Tell Us More ...</h2>

      <div class="profileField"> 
      Height
      <input size="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="2" name="user[height_feet]" id="user_height_feet" /> ft. 

      <input size="2" class="form-control" type="text" value="1" name="user[height_inches]" id="user_height_inches" /> in. 
      </div>

      <div class="profileField">
      <label for="user_weight">Weight</label>
      <input size="3" class="form-control" type="text" name="user[weight]" id="user_weight" /> lbs.
      </div>

      <div class="profileField">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" method="put" class="button" />
      </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The class for the button is

```
.button {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555555;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cecece #bababa #a8a8a8;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 2px 2px;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1 0%, #dfdfdf 70%, #dadada 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1 0%, #dfdfdf 70%, #dadada 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1 0%, #dfdfdf 70%, #dadada 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1f1f1 0%, #dfdfdf 70%, #dadada 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fdfdfd, inset 0 0 0 1px #eaeaea, 0 1px #a8a8a8, 0 3px #bbbbbb, 0 4px #a8a8a8, 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fdfdfd, inset 0 0 0 1px #eaeaea, 0 1px #a8a8a8, 0 3px #bbbbbb, 0 4px #a8a8a8, 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.button:hover, .button:active {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  border-top-color: #c9c9c9;
}

.button:active, .button.green:active, .button.blue:active, .button.yellow:active, .button.red:active, .button.purple:active, .button.grey:active, .button.black:active {
  vertical-align: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 1px 13px 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 1px white;
}
```

IF I remove the ‘class=“button”’ attribute from the button, then the div with id=“profile” does not move down when I click on the button, but then I lose all my styling on the button.  How do I adjust things so that only my button moves down when I click on it as opposed to the entire form?

**Edit:** The container (element with id="profile") has the below CSS.  I'm tryihng to center everything in the middle of the screen

```
#profile {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `margin-bottom` is removed in the `:active` state. You can add the same amount to `margin-top` to cover the gap.

```
.button:active {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to change the size of form. I think that you have a fixed height of form and the button is at bottom and your button initially have bottom margin 5px which when clicked reduces to 0.

So your button will take extra space when it is clicked.

I don't think you  need this but check it if some css margin property may have slipped of your brain. [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp)

Comment: I've included the CSS for the container element (that contains the form).  I don't include a margin element, but I am trying to center my form in the middle of teh screen.

Comment: BTW I mentioned about button margin(first attribute of button class) not the form margin. I was telling to increase the height of the form (from the heck margin comes in between?). Do you have problems in centering the form also?

Comment: I'm able to center everything just fine.  If I take out the button margin as you suggest, it no longer looks like the button is being pressed down when you click on it.  How can I keep that effect without making the entire form move?  I created this JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem -- https://jsfiddle.net/05qxeaok/2/ .